# How to get this regex working?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

i have a small problem, i want to find in

`<tr><td>3</td><td>foo</td><td>2</td>`

the foo, i use:

`$<tr><td>\d</td><td>(.*)</td>$`

to find the foo, but it dont work because it dont match with the `</td>` at the end of foo but with the `</td>` at the end of the string

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want to use a real html parser, not a regular expression. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Seth, others: Okay, saying the HTML parser thing as a *comment* is the way to go, instead of wasting an answer with that incorrectly. Good show.

Comment: Also: Who's downvoting the question? It's a good question, well-asked. (+1 to offset)

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but info; with regards to developing/testing RegExs there are some AMAZING tools out there which will parse them in English for you and show you exactly what they're doing along with full-featured building tools. Personally I prefer Expresso ( http://ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm ), but I'm sure there are others. Can help you solve almost any RegEx need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the `.*` lazy instead of greedy. Read more about lazy vs greedy [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).
Your end of string anchors (`$`) also don't make sense. Try:

```
<tr><td>\d<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>
```

*(As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/3mf3A2xEQR).)*

NOTE: I don't advocate using regex to parse HTML. But some times the task at hand is simple enough to be handled by regex, for which a full-blown XML parser is overkill (for example: this question). Knowing to pick the "right tool for the job" is an important skill in programming.

Comment: I'm just going to say it wasn't me (even though I did downvote another post for saying HTML isn't regular and should not be parsed with regex). You're actually answering the question. (EDIT: +1 for you)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
^<tr><td>\d</td><td>(.*?)</td>
```

(insert obligatory comment about not using regex to parse xml)

Answer (score 0):

Your leading `$` should be a `^`.

If you don't want to match all of the way to the end of the string, don't use a `$` at the end.  However, since `*` is greedy, it'll grab as much as it can.  Some regex implementations have a non-greedy version which would work, but you probably just want to change `(.*)` to `([^<]*)`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm curious what was wrong enough about this answer to demand a downvote.  Alas.